# Footnote text inside a bookcover fails to display

Tags: footnotes, bookcover

I tried two different ways to add a footnote to the content of the `front` part, where the title is expected, both fail to show the footnote text. How could I correct that, please?

```
\documentclass[trimmed=true]{bookcover}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{xparse}

%coverwidth=〈length〉
%coverheight=〈length〉
%spinewidth=〈length〉
%flapwidth=〈length〉
%marklength=〈length〉
%bleedwidth=〈length〉
%markthick=〈length〉
%markcolor=〈color〉
%〈10pt|11pt|12pt〉
%trimmed=〈true|false〉

\NewDocumentCommand{\booktitleA}{}{FIRST}
\NewDocumentCommand{\booktitleB}{}{SECOND}
\NewDocumentCommand{\booktitleC}{}{THIRD}
\NewDocumentCommand{\booktitleCfn}{}{precision}
\NewDocumentCommand{\booktitleD}{}{FOURTH}

\begin{document}

% One-piece background parts: <----
% bg back flap,
% bg back,
% bg spine,
% bg front,
% bg front flap >------------------
% One-piece foreground parts: <----
% back flap,
% back,
% spine,
% front,
% front flap,
% above back,
% above front,
% below back,
% below front >--------------------

\begin{bookcover}

  %\bookcovercomponent{center}{above front}{\color{blue}Remark above front} % You won't see it if [trimmed=true]
  \bookcovercomponent{center}{spine}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\bfseries\large \booktitleA~\booktitleB }}

  \bookcovercomponent{normal}{front}{

    \begin{center}
      \bfseries

    {\large \booktitleA}\\
    \vspace*{\fill}
    {\huge \booktitleB}\\
    \vspace*{\fill}
%   {\large \booktitleC\footnote{\booktitleCfn}} % TRY # 1 
    {\large \booktitleC\footnotemark[1]}
    \vspace*{\fill}\\
    \keyfig{lw=0.3,cstar={}}{example-image-a.png}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    {\huge \booktitleD}

    \end{center}
\footnotetext{\booktitleCfn} % Try # 2
  }

\end{bookcover}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Where do you want to place the footnote? Below of `\booktitleD`,i.e FOURTH ?

Comment: Ideally I'd like a solution for both, that is immediately after the mark, and at the bottom of the front part, and pick the one that looks best with the actual, not dummy, bookcover I'm working on.