# How to make a title of two or more lines? (revisited)

Tags: line-breaking, bookcover

This is a sequel to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56222/how-to-make-a-title-of-two-or-more-lines#56224). There are three lines in the title, and an awkward gap between the first ('AAAA...') and second ('OF'). How to get rid of it?

PS: I am showing the title THIRD, so I can link to it [from another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509496/footnote-text-inside-a-bookcover-fails-to-display).

```
\documentclass[trimmed=true]{bookcover}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{xparse}

%coverwidth=〈length〉
%coverheight=〈length〉
%spinewidth=〈length〉
%flapwidth=〈length〉
%marklength=〈length〉
%bleedwidth=〈length〉
%markthick=〈length〉
%markcolor=〈color〉
%〈10pt|11pt|12pt〉
%trimmed=〈true|false〉

\NewDocumentCommand{\booktitleA}{}{FIRST}
\NewDocumentCommand{\booktitleB}{}{SECOND}
\NewDocumentCommand{\booktitleC}{}{THIRD}
\NewDocumentCommand{\booktitleCfn}{}{precision}
\NewDocumentCommand{\booktitleD}{}{FOURTH}

\begin{document}

% One-piece background parts: <----
% bg back flap,
% bg back,
% bg spine,
% bg front,
% bg front flap >------------------
% One-piece foreground parts: <----
% back flap,
% back,
% spine,
% front,
% front flap,
% above back,
% above front,
% below back,
% below front >--------------------

\begin{bookcover}

  %\bookcovercomponent{center}{above front}{\color{blue}Remark above front} % You won't see it if [trimmed=true]
  \bookcovercomponent{center}{spine}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\bfseries\large \booktitleA~\booktitleB }}


  \bookcovercomponent{normal}{front}{


    \begin{center}
      \bfseries

    {\large \booktitleA}

    \vspace*{\fill}

    {\huge AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\ OF\\ BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}

    \vspace*{\fill}

    {\large \booktitleC}\footnotemark[1]\\
      % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509496/footnote-text-inside-a-bookcover-fails-to-display
      \begin{minipage}{0.2 \textwidth}
      \hrule
      \noindent \footnotemark[1]\scriptsize \booktitleCfn
    \end{minipage}



    \vspace*{\fill}

    \keyfig{lw=0.3,cstar={}}{example-image-a.png}

    \vspace*{\fill}

    {\huge \booktitleD}

    \end{center}
    \footnotetext{\booktitleCfn} % Try # 2

  }

\end{bookcover}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `{\huge AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\ OF\\ BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\par}` or possibly better `{\huge AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par OF\par BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\par}`

Comment: It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the title in an object that can be broken easily across multiple lines, like a `tabular`, for example:

```
% ...
{\huge \begin{tabular}{c}
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA \\
             OF             \\
     BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
  \end{tabular}}
% ...
```

[image]